# How to add or edit autocompletions in Sublime text 3?

Tags: autocomplete, sublime-text-3

I am using Sublime text 3 build 3065 to edit HTML and PHP code. The built in HTML tag completions are awesome, just typing p and pressing tab gets you `<p></p>` with the cursor in the right place between the tags.

But there are some things missing, like `<hr />` and some that I would like to tweak, so how do I edit or add to the autocompletions that are built into Sublime text 3?

I gather that in Sublime text 2 it was easy because they were stored in a text file, but I don't think this is the case for version 3.

thanks for any help, David

Answer (score 0):

You should just use [snippets](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html) with a appropriate tab trigger.

I personally have a snippet to insert an arbitrary HTML tag quickly:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<$1>$0</$1>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>t</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js, source.javascript, text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

This is saved as `t.sublime-snippet` in my User directory. Note that you can create arbitrary subdirectories, the files still will be recognized by Sublime.

I press *t* followed by *tab* and write the tag name - say `span` - press *tab* again and write what's between the tags.